# Macbook crashed and I do not see "Restore tabs" in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mac, crash, browser-tabs

I am using Macbook Pro with macOS Catalina 10.15.7 with Google Chrome Version 86.0.4240.183 (x86_64).

I usually keep multiple Chrome windows open (each with multiple tabs). Yesterday night, my Mac crashed. When it restarted, Chrome returned only to the window that I was working on before the crash. All other windows are gone and I do not see the "Restore xx tabs" option under History either.

Is there a way to restore all other windows with their tabs? I could do that earlier using the Restore Tabs option.

Comment: If Chrome isn’t giving you the option to restore the tabs either it’s not configured to restore the session or the session data has been lost.  Chrome is notorious for doing that

Answer (score 0):

Chrome only offers the 'restore tabs' if Chrome itself crashed.
If it was closed by the OS (as a consequence of a reboot or crash of underlying OS processes), it assumes that the closing was ok.

You can still go in the Chrome menu under 'Recent Tabs', and will find your chunk of '14 tabs' (or however many you had), and if you select that, all of them open again.

Here an example screenshot from iOS (I have no Mac, and it might look different there):
[image: screenshot from iOS]

Comment: Where do you find this "recent tabs"? As of 2022/01/10 I don't see that entry on the Chrome menu (Three dots)